# Start Django Project Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I am trying to create a new Django project but running

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
      from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 68
      commands = {name: 'django.core' for name in find_commands(__path__[0])}
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I must be missing some libraries or some paths could be invalid. However, I am yet to find a solution.

My Django files are located here:

```
/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your **system python** to start a project which is `Python2.6`. And you've installed `Django 1.7` into your `Python 2.6` environment, but [`Django 1.7` dropped support for `Python 2.6`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#python-compatibility):

> Django 1.7 requires Python 2.7 or above, though we highly recommend
>   the latest minor release. Support for Python 2.6 has been dropped and
>   support for Python 3.4 has been added.

In particular, the error you see is because of the *dictionary comprehension syntax* which was introduced in `Python 2.7`.

Comment: I see, so should I drop back to 1.6 to create this project? Or is there a better way in 1.7?

Comment: @Jon try activating your virtual environment and then call `django-admin startproject myproject`.

Comment: Can't you switch to Python 2.7? It was released over 4 years ago.

Comment: @Matthias the virtual env has python 2.7. It seems I had two instances of django-admin and I picked the wrong one... I had /opt/.virtualenvs/smart/bin/django-admin.py and /opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py...

Comment: @Jon what is the output of `which django-admin`?

Comment: /usr/bin/django-admin, is that my local version?

Comment: @Jon this is your system version tied to `python2.6`. And this is the problem, you need the one in your virtual environment.

Comment: Ah I thought it was something like that. Thanks for your help.